# div with z-index refuses to be placed on top of another div

Tags: css, html, z-index

I have 3 divs. A blue one, a black one and a yellow one. Now I want the yellow div be placed on top of the black one (both have the same size). Some CSS and using z-index should do the trick, but it aint working.

Perhaps someone has an idea why, since I am a bit stuck on this. Please see my Fiddle with the complete html and css code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/xQVYu/

Kind regards,
Maurice

Comment: Is `#s3` supposed to be on top of `#s2`?

Comment: You'll likely get a better response if you pare that fiddle down to only the essential elements.

Comment: As well as including the element names in the description of what should occur...

Comment: What browser are you testing in?  I've had problems with it working depending on the browser.

Comment: why would you want the yellow div to completely cover up the black div?

Comment: To all, I already took 75% off the css before putting it in the fiddle :) and tested it in all browsers before posting. Thanks for the other tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the position of these elements so that they overlap:

```
#s2, #s3 { top: 0; }
```

Comment: They're both position absolutely as they should be. Just add top:0 (or any other value but same for both containers)

Comment: Also, add a `position: relative;` to its parent.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it! Adding the `position: relative;` to `s0` was what really was missing in my CSS!

Answer (score 1):

Hey i think you want this

Your define your s0 div position relative and #s3 define position absolute and adjust according  to your layout left and top

```
#s0{
position:relative;
}

#s3{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 pink;
    left: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 102px;
}
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/xQVYu/4/